# Xamarin.Forms 1.4.3-pre2 compilation error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I upgraded Xamarin.Forms to the 1.4.3-pre2 version.
I didn't change anything in the code and I'm getting this compilation error:

Target XamlC:
: error : Error initializing task XamlCTask: Not registered task XamlCTask.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio or Xamarin Studio? Does it say where the error occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried the first answer - it don't have solved the problem for me.
I had to:
- close the solution in VS
- open the files:
 - AppName.Android.csproj
 - AppName.iOS.csproj
 - AppName.Winphone.csproj
 in the sub-folders of the solution with editor.
**Then I had to remove (just delete) two old references to .forms:**

```
  <Import Project="..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.1.2.3.6257\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10\Xamarin.Forms.targets"
```

and

```
 Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.1.2.3.6257\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10\Xamarin.Forms.targets')" />
```

Where it seems, as the deletion of the import has done the job...

Note: there were also references to the **new** version stored in the .csproj-file.

Then reopen the solution in VS, clean and rebuild.

**With these manual changes, I'm now able to further build for all platforms.**

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the solution, deleting your `\packages`, `\bin` and `\obj` folders. Then reopen the solution and wait for the packages to get restored (or restore them manually at the solution level), then rebuild your solution.

Some packages (XF included) bring along build scripts, such as `Xamarin.Forms.targets` and old libraries may interfere or new libraries may not be recognized on update. I've found the manual clean-up resolves them.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips to follow:

- Update Xamarin.forms to the last version on your solution
- Delete Xamarin.forms nugget package and install it again
- Check that there is only one `xamarin.Forms` package (only one version) in the package repository of your project. If you find two or more, delete them and keep only the last version associated to nuget pakcages insatlled to your project.
- Remove “packages” from project repository and rebuild project
- Get xamarin example project from [here](https://www.xamarin.com/prebuilt?utm_source=visualstudio&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=ios-prebuilt&utm_campaign=vs) and try to build it. If you d'ont have error, try to find difference between your project and the working one.
- Check that there are no special characters in the path of your project (#, {, [, +, ...)